# Asynchronous programming actually takes total same time for execution as that of synchronous

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, asynchronous

I am always wondering this: Suppose, in a shop, one executive is serving client A. Now, same executive turns to client B and serves for sometime, again to C and then again to A and so on.

Now, here, overall time for execution is same right i.e A+B+C time = A's time+ B's time + C's time individually.

I don't see any good reason on this timing aspect. Yet why asynchronous is given vital importance ? Especially in electronic product development softwares ? I lost an interview because of a silly question in Asynchronous programming. :(

Can somebody explain ? I know the book definition of asynchronous programming, but practically I want to get satisfied where it can be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, synchronous programming is when client A makes his order and waits for the clerk to complete the order, then client B gives his order and waits for completion and so on. With more than one clerk, clients still await for completion.

Asynchronous is when client A makes his order and the clerk says "ok, will be done, you can go now" and client A **immediately** walks away satisfied and the clerk asks someone else to do the job then immediately turns to client B and so on.

The overall execution time is similar but the waiting time is shorter as tasks are immediatelly confirmed and executed later, probably by someone else (another thread, a thread pool, a queue).

Comment: thank you for the very easy explanation. But I am confused between "Execution time" and "Waiting time". My doubt is, if the "Execution time" is same for both asynch and synch, then whats the idea ? My worry is all about total execution time which remains same. I understand other things what you said.

Comment: You can't magically shrink the execution time. If you create additional threads, you can execute concurrently. Asynchronous programming goes further, not only you execute concurrently but also you don't make the client waiting for the completion. The client is free to continue with any other activities and gets notified when the asynchronous task completes.

Comment: WIktor, thank you, that answers my question, however, I will do a good reading on asynchronous programming and multi threading.... :)

Comment: Learn how asynchronous delegates work. This should clear up confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the direction Wiktor, sure, I will learn the delegates and asynchronous delegates. One complement by the way, you resemble one of my client(Onsite developer at client side who is more than 25 years experienced in Java/NET and related web technologies, databases.) He is very interesting and a great programmer too, I learned a lot with him when I was working at onsite with him, a guy with smiling face, very young attractive looks, humorous interesting personality, although he is 46 years old. His name is Kris :) :) Thank you again.Having seen you, I got his thoughts on my mind....

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of terms that need to be defined when dealing with this topic.

Asynchronous - The ability to continue to do work without blocking (ie, not waiting for a task to complete before starting another task).  Asynch tasks are often accomplished using multi-threading, but it is no necessarily required to do so.

Multi-threading - Having multiple distinct "threads" of execution in a process.  Often times there are many threads happening in your program without your even knowing it.

Multi-Processing - As Multi-Threading, but when your code is sensitive to executing concurrently on more than one Processor or Core.

Concurrency - This term tends to be used in a lot of ways, but means more than one thing happening "at the same time".  It can mean either task switching (as in one core/processor swapping between threads) or literal concurrency (multiple cores running code simultaneously).  In programming, it typically refers to a programs ability to reliably handle concurrent tasks (for instance, a website handling more than one user at a time, we would say this is "concurrent safe" or "concurrent aware").

Asynchronous programming is all about not waiting for jobs to complete unless you have no other work to do.  Even then, you're often waiting not for the jobs to complete, but for more work to come in.

So think of it like this.  You take your spouse/partner out to dinner, and you're waiting in line for the hostess to seat you.  As each person comes in, she greets them, finds a table, then walks them back to the table, takes their drink order, submits it, then walks back to the front desk to greet the next person.  That's synchronous work.

Now, you go to another restaurant and this time, the hostess stays put, takes each persons name as they come in, and as a table becomes available, she has your server seat you while she stays at the desk checking for new tables opening up, and for new customers to walk in.  This is Asynchronous.

Asynchronous programming is typically accomplished via Multi-threading/processing but does not necessarily require it.  For instance, sometimes Asynchrony can be achieved using polling mechanisms, where a program is waiting for a users input, but it keeps doing some work, checking periodically for whether the user has entered anything.  This doesn't require any multi-threading (technically, the user input in most OS's runs on it's own process or thread, so ultimately it could be considered that, but from the applications perspective it does not), but is considered asynchronous.

The key thing to understand about Asynchronous programming is that it does not make a program run faster.  It may make a program Respond faster, and it may (via responding efficiently and managing multi-threading)  make a program finish multiple tasks faster (or perform more work in the same time period), but it doesn't actually *run* faster any more than two Olympic sprinters running side by side finish the race any faster.  Any 1 task will still take the same amount of time.

Asynchronous programming can get more work done in the same time period, assuming there are excess CPU cycles or IO bandwidth to accomplish it because it uses resources more efficiently, but it has many of the same limitations of multi-threading.  Using the two runners analogy, if you give two runners each a package, then you can deliver 2 packagers in roughly the same amount of time you could deliver 1.  But you cannot deliver 1 package twice as fast.  This is like how 9 women cannot make a baby in 1 month.

Likewise, if you give two runners each a package, but they have to use an elevator that only allows one person to fit in it.. you can't deliver the two packages in the same time frame unless there are two elevators.  This is like an I/O bandwidth limitation.

And, of course, if you only have one runner, it doesn't matter if you try to use asynch or not, it will still take 2 times as long to deliver 2 packages (well, 4x actually, since the runner has to run back, wait for the package to be signed for, etc..), although asynch *could* slightly improve performance of the input queue (the person accepting the package for delivery, who then throws it on a conveyor belt for the runner to pick up).

Comment: Hi Mystere, that was GOLDMINE and Fruitful explanation. I have learned many terminologies PROPERLY and could understand the most important differences. Previously, I really couldn't differentiate all these. You have cared to understand to the thought level into my soul/mind and have answered beautifully. Thank you so much for your time writing this for me, I appreciate your attitude to help and your modesty. I have one doubt : Can I say all the aforementioned concepts are "parallel programming" in two words ?

Comment: @Divine - In a loose sense, yes.. but not exactly.  Parallel Programming does sort of encompass many of the same concepts, but is more about breaking work up into units that can be executed concurrently to reduce overall time.  It focuses on optimizing your code to utilize all available resources (or as many as you want to use) to accomplish the task very efficiently.  This is why it's called Parallel, as in running multiple side-by-side tasks.  For instance, calculating a large equation by breaking it down into multiple parts and executing each part at the same time.

Comment: @Divine - Parallel programming often concentrates on the problems involved with this concurrent execution, such as dealing with dependencies and precedence (when one task requires the output of another task, but other tasks don't, etc..)

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know the meaning of Parallel programming, I appreciate your helping nature. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Asynchronous programming provides two major benefits:

1. (On the client side) Responsiveness. Instead of blocking the UI thread waiting for some operation to complete, you can remain responsive to the user.
2. (On the server side) Scalability. Instead of blocking a thread waiting for some operation to complete, you can have it do work for other requests while waiting.

Also, asynchronous programming enables a form of concurrency that is not related to multithreading. For example, you can easily start several operations and then (asynchronously) wait for them all to complete. This is easier, less error-prone, and more scalable than traditional multithreading (parallel processing).

Comment: thank you Stephen, I should learn the difference between Multi threading and asynchronous programming first. Will learn that....

Comment: I wouldn't say it's unrelated to multithreading, because it's typically accomplished via multithreading.  However, it's not precisely the same thing, and deals with different issues.

Comment: @MystereMan: Modern asynchronous programming (`async`/`await`) is not typically accomplished via multithreading. It is entirely independent.

Comment: @StephenCleary - async / await are implemented via .net Task infrastructure, which behind the scenes is implemented via IOCP thread pool.  So yes, it is multi-threaded.  It's just not application managed multi-threading.

Comment: @MystereMan: It's not multithreading in the sense that a background thread is used to perform the operation. It is "multithreading" in the sense that the app will spend a sub-millisecond per operation within an IOCP thread. And if you accept this definition of multithreading, you must also accept that *every* .NET app is multithreaded due to the finalizer thread - not a very useful definition IMO.

Comment: @MystereMan: Oh, and not all `await`s use `Task`s; any type that matches the "awaitable" pattern can be awaited. And not all `Task`s use the IOCP; two examples that come to mind are `Task.Run` (uses the regular thread pool) and `Task.Delay`. :)

Comment: @StephenCleary - I would say that yes, every .net application is multithreaded, whereas not every native app is.  IOCP's are, in particular, multi-threaded because, even though it only runs for a moment, the callback executes on a threadpool thread, and thus the app must deal with multithreading issues, such as UI synchronization, or thread local storage.  Yes, the compiler may hide much of this from you, but that doesn't change the fact that the work still has to be done.  In any event, I think it's entirely inaccurate to say it's "unrelated".  It is related, but different.

Answer (score 1):

Well. Say that you download two files from the Internet. You have 10 Megabyte / s download capacity. The two files that you download (from separate servers) have upload capacity 1 Mb / s each. What is best, to download file A, then file B, or both files A and B at the "same" time? Even if the total time of processing data for the CPU is the same, you will still finish faster.

Especially IO-bound operations have a lot of waiting time. That time is more well spent doing other stuff, than just waiting.

Or if you prefer the customer scenario. Say that what the customer's buy are trips with your taxi. It's a lot faster to split your threading capable car in two, and drive both customers simultaneously, instead of driving one first, and then the other. Even if the split driver has to do the same amount of total work.

Comment: Thank you Sami for the explanation, it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well to take your own example, imagine every customer has to take several 5 seconds pauses to get their money out, sign something, read something else, etc.

If your clerk waits for the customer, he's wasting a lot of time whereas he can switch to another customer and begin/continue another transaction during those 5 seconds.

Asynchronous processing is a good thing because it allows to to reclaim time otherwise wasted by waiting on something else.  In programming, those other things are usually disk/network I/O or long background tasks.

Comment: Thank you P, thats satisfying and comprehensive explanation for me, I will start learning asynchronous programming slowly. Cheers

Comment: @Divine It's a pleasure.  Since you tagged this C#, I recommend you look into the new `async` and `await` keywords in C# 5 (.NET 4.5).  They're an amazing abstraction of asynchronous tasks.